# Assigning elements of one one character array to another

Tags: c, arrays, variable-assignment, character-arrays

I have a C program with two character arrays `a` and `b`.

I am getting a run time error at this particular line

```c
a[j] = b[i];// i and j are integers.
```

Is this legal for two character arrays. I think it is. Why could I be getting an error then?

Edit: Running this program later gave me no errors without any changes. I don't really know how. Maybe you can tell me why that could have happened instead.

Here is the whole program:

```c
char *ConvertCodeToHex(char *code)   
{
    char nibble[4];
    char hexvalue[4];
    int i;int j=0;int k = 0;
    printf("\nCheck2");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)  //Goes through each element of the array
    {
        printf("\nCheck'i'%d", i+1);
        if((i+5)%4 == 0)        
        {
            printf("\nCheck'i2'%d", i+1);
            hexvalue[k] = BinaryToHex(nibble);  
            j = 0;                              
            printf("\nCheck'k'%d", 1+k);
            k++;
        }
        printf("\nPre-asstcheck");
        nibble[j] = code[i];        //RUN TIME Error
        printf("\nPost-asstcheck");
        j++;
        printf("Assignmentcheck");
    }
    strncpy(finalhex, hexvalue, 4); //finalhex is a global character array
    printf("%s", finalhex);
    return finalhex;
}


void main()
{
    char arr[16] = {'1','0','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','0'};
    printf("Check1");
    printf("%s", ConvertCodeToHex(arr));
    printf("LastCheck");
}
```

Comment: The program crashes at this point.

Comment: This question is bad quality. What language are you using? How are these two arrays declared (e.g., local or global, statically-allocated or dynamically-allocated)? And most importantly (probably the reason for the runtime exception you're experiencing) - What are their sizes and what are the values of the indexes that you're using? Publish your code properly, we're not supposed to guess it!!!

Comment: Hmm, the line is perfectly valid. Well there could be so many reasons that my crystal ball fails on me. You have to provide more context (surrounding code), or we will be unable to help you.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry. I posted the whole function now.

Comment: Your arrays `finalhex` and `hexvalue` are not null-terminated, and that by itself is going to cause some major problems when you pass any one of them as input argument to a string operation (`printf("%s", finalhex)` for example). In addition, by returning the local array `finalhex`, you are invoking undefined behavior. The contents of this array are guaranteed to be valid only within the scope of its declaration (i.e., **inside** the function). You are essentially returning an address on the stack of this function, which may contain any value once outside the function.

Comment: As to the runtime exception itself - it is most likely because the the value of variable `j` is larger than 3. Debug your code step-by-step in order to make sure of that. If you don't know how to do that, then now is a good time to learn. It will help you a lot in the future, and will probably save you the time spent in posting may similar questions here. To be more specific, it seems that debugging is pretty much all you need to do in order to solve the given problem at hand.

Comment: It is not displayed, but finalhex is global.

Comment: I do not want to null terminate these arrays as they are not strings but for conversion to numbers. Is there another way to display finalhex considering it is not null-terminated.

Comment: Additionally, when j reaches the value of three i assign it back to 0 after calling BinaryToHex

Comment: What do you mean "it is not displayed"??? Is this your code or what? Please provide all the necessary details. Also, please see the addition to my previous comment, it is rather important.

Comment: No you're not. You're assigning it to 0 when `(i+5)%4 == 0`!!!

Comment: It was an oversight. My mistake. It IS however commented that finalhex is a global array. I do not know where the error got fixed, but the function stopped crashing when I did nothing. Also- No,  j does not exceed 3. I debugged the code and found it myself. Also, j becomes 3 at the point when (i+5)%4 ==0. Please read the program carefully before pointing out things I have already taken care of.